# Weight of a constant diagonal $(0,1)$ matrix

Tags: probability

Consider $n$ by $n$ matrices with entries that are $0$ or $1$.  I am interested in the subset of these matrices where each of the $2n-1$ diagonals is constant. That is each diagonal is either made up of all $1$s or all $0$s.  The weight of a matrix is just the number of $1$s.  Let $X_{n}$ be a random variable that represents the weight of a uniformly chosen matrix with this constant diagonal property. We know from the linearity of expectation that

$$\mathbb{E}(X_{n}) = \frac{n^2}{2} .$$

But what does the distribution of  $X_{n}$ converge to when $n$ is large?  Experimentally I can see that it is (very) approximately normal but I can't work out the variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an $n\times n$ matrix we have $n$ diagonal entries, and the remaining entries (there are $n(n-1)$ of them) are "free".

So I think we should have one random uniform 0-or-1 variable $Y$ for the diagonal, and then random variables $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_{n(n-1)}$ for the remaining entries. All random variables $Y$ and $Z_i$ are independent and identically distributed.

Then the weight is

$$X = nY + \sum_{i=1}^{n(n-1)}Z_i$$

For huge values of $n$ the first term will almost surely be negligible, so $X$ is approximately just the sum of a whole bunch of independent identically distributed (uniform 0-or-1) random variables. I seem to be saying that the constant diagonal requirement is insignificant "in the limit".

---

**Edit:** When all $2n-1$ diagonals need to be constant, not just the main diagonal, consider random variables $Y_{-n+1},Y_{-n+2},\ldots,Y_{n-1}$ where $Y_i$ corresponds to the (minor) diagonal positioned $i$ places under the main diagonal. Then as far as I can see

$$X = Y_{-n+1}+2Y_{-n+2}+3Y_{-n+3}+\dots+(n-1)Y_{-1}+nY_0+(n-1)Y_1+\dots+2Y_{n-2}+Y_{n-1}$$

which leads to

$$\operatorname{Var}X = (1+2^2+3^2+\dots+(n-1)^2+n^2+(n-1)^2+\dots+2^2+1)\operatorname{Var}Y_0$$

(since all $\operatorname{Var}Y_i$ are equal) which according to [the article Octahedral number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_number) is

$$\operatorname{Var}X = \frac{n(2n^2+1)}{3}\operatorname{Var}Y_0$$

or

$$\operatorname{Var}X = \frac{n(2n^2+1)}{12}$$

Comment: Oh sorry I was unclear... there are $2n-1$ diagonals. You are right they are all independently all $1$ or all $0$.  This seems solvable now. Thank you.

Comment: @Anush OK, I read your question as if only the main diagonal was required to be constant. Maybe you need $X = Y_{-n+1}+2Y_{-n+2}+3Y_{-n+3}+\dots+(n-1)Y_{-1}+nY_0+(n-1)Y_1+\dots+3Y_{n-3}+2Y_{n-2}+Y_{n-1}$ instead.